# What is the difference between split() and replace(' ','')?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I want to create a list of the input

```
3 4 5 6 7
```

without the spacings. Is there a technical difference between `list(map(int, input().split()))` and `list(map(int,input().replace(' ','')))`?

I am inputting a list of this sort for a question [on HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/piling-up/problem). The `split()` version seems to always work, but the `replace(' ','')` version seems to only work for short length inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list(map(int,input().replace(' ','')))` will fail if your numbers have more than two digits since it converts each character to an int.

Example:

```
>>> inp = '1 2 3 50'

>>> list(map(int, inp.replace(' ','')))
[1, 2, 3, 5, 0]

>>> list(map(int, inp.split()))
[1, 2, 3, 50]
```

For the same reason, it also isn't able to handle negative values or floats.

Answer (score 0):

The two methods are very different. Replace() returns an str object whereas split() returns a list of strings. Your map() function will be iterating over different types leading to the issue Loocid described.